# No bean found for definition [SpyDefinition... when using @SpyBean

Tags: spring, kotlin, mockito, integration-testing, spring-kafka

I have an application that listens for Kafka messages using `@KafkaListener` inside of a `@Component`. Now I'd like to make an integration test with a Kafka test container (which spins up Kafka in the background). In my test I want to verify that the listener method was called and finished, however when I use `@SpyBean` in my test I get:

> `No bean found for definition [SpyDefinition@7a939c9e name = '', typeToSpy = com.demo.kafka.MessageListener, reset = AFTER]`

I'm using Kotling, important classes:

**Class to test**

```
@Component
class MessageListener(private val someRepository: SomeRepository){

    @KafkaListener
    fun listen(records: List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>>) {
         // do something with someRepository
    }
}
```

**Base test class**

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class KafkaContainerTests {

    // some functionality to spin up kafka testcontainer

}
```

**Test class**

```
class MessageListenerTest @Autowired constructor(
        private val someRepository: SomeRepository
) : KafkaContainerTests() {


    @SpyBean
    private lateinit var messageListenerSpy: MessageListener

    private var messageListenerLatch = CountDownLatch(1)

    @BeforeAll
    fun setupLatch() {
        logger.debug("setting up latch")

        doAnswer {
            it.callRealMethod()
            messageListenerLatch.count
        }.whenever(messageListenerSpy).listen(any())
    }

    @Test
    fun testListener(){
        sendKafkaMessage(someValidKafkaMessage)

        // assert that the listen method is being called & finished
        assertTrue(messageListenerLatch.await(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
        // and assert someRepository is called
    }
}
```

The reason I am confused is that when I add the MessageListener to the `@Autowired` constructor of the `MessageListenerTest` it does get injected successfully.

Why is the test unable to find the bean when using `@SpyBean`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me with Java:

```java
@SpringBootTest
class So58184716ApplicationTests {

    @SpyBean
    private Listener listener;

    @Test
    void test(@Autowired KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) throws InterruptedException {
        template.send("so58184716", "foo");
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        willAnswer(inv -> {
            inv.callRealMethod();
            latch.countDown();
            return null;
        }).given(this.listener).listen("foo");
        assertThat(latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).isTrue();
        verify(this.listener).listen("foo");
    }

}

@SpringBootApplication
public class So58184716Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So58184716Application.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so58184716").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }
}

@Component
class Listener {

    @KafkaListener(id = "so58184716", topics = "so58184716")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: I just used IntelliJ to convert that project to Kotlin and it still works fine for me.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for your answer, although your example is slightly different it's very useful. It shows that it definitely has something to do with bean initialization order of my test setup. Investigation continues :)